# Talking to container on Kubernetes (GKE) from other container

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an API written in `Express`, that connects to a `Mongo` container. When I spin these up locally, I can connect to the mongo instance using something like `mongodb://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}` and setting `.env` variables.

What I am struggling to understand, is once this deployed to GKE, how will my API connect to the mongo container / pod?

It won't be running on localhost I assume, so perhaps I will need to use the internal IP created?

Should it actually be connecting via a `service`? What would that service look like?

I am struggling to find docs on exactly where I am stuck so I am thinking I am missing something really obvious.

I'm free new to `GKE` so any examples would help massively.

Comment: [Connect a Front End to a Back End Using a Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/) in the Kubernetes documentation is probably a reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mongodb deployment and a mongodb service of type ClusterIP, which basically means that your api will be able to connect to the db internally. If you want to connect your db from outside, create a service of type LoadBalancer or other service types (see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/))

With a service of type ClusterIP, let's say you give it a `name` of `mongodbservice` under `metadata` key. Then your api can connect to it at `mongodb://mongodbservice:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}`

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to deploy mongodb, probably as a StatefulSet so it can use stable persistent storage.  You'll need to configure a StorageClass for the persistent storage.  Then you'll want to expose it as a Service.  Here's an example on [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/01/running-mongodb-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets/)

If you use Helm (hint, do it) it's a lot easier.  You can be up and running with a single command

```
helm install stable/mongodb
```

The output of the helm install contains some helpful instructions for connecting to your new mongodb cluster.